# Istio Keeps On Showing TcpProxyValidationError Errors

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I initially created an EnvoyFilter to apply `idle_timeout` of `5s` to outbound requests originating from workloads with label `app: mecha-dev`.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: tcp-idle-timeout
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: mecha-dev
  filters:
    - listenerMatch:
        listenerType: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
        listenerProtocol: TCP
      filterName: envoy.tcp_proxy
      filterType: NETWORK
      filterConfig:
        idle_timeout: 5s
```

However, the filter did not work for me and I found out it was because my cluster is using `istio v1.2.5` which is a very old version and does not support `EnvoyFilters` properly and the envoy API for the same have been deprecated.

Therefore, I deleted the `EnvoyFilter` using `kubectl`.

But, even after deletion of the filter the `istio-proxy` sidecar containers keep on showing me the following error again and again:

```
[2021-05-11 11:59:14.109][22][warning][config] [external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_mux_subscription_impl.cc:73] gRPC config for type.googleapis.com/envoy.api.v2.Listener rejected: Error adding/updating listener(s) 10.155.0.113_443: Proto constraint validation failed (TcpProxyValidationError.StatPrefix: ["value length must be at least " '\x01' " bytes"]): idle_timeout {
  seconds: 5
}
```

I deleted the pods and re-created new ones but this error keeps on showing up. Is there anything else I need to clean up or delete to get rid of this error?

Comment: Have you deleted workloads only? Have you restarted controlplane as well (pods in `istio-system` namespace)?

Comment: @Kyslik there are a bunch of pods in ```istio-system``` namespace, do I gotta restart all?

Comment: Unless you run your production workloads on that cluster, yes. You gotta test things like this one way or another... I don't remember what components Istio 1.2 have, but I'd start with pilot or mixer.

Comment: It is not a prod workload so I can test these out.

Comment: @Kyslik after restarting pilot and mixer the errors were gone. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting Istio controlplane should fix the issue on hand (pods in `istio-system`, most likely pilot).

More importantly do not run Istio 1.2 its very outdated version with many bugs and security issues.

Comment: Yes, we are abolishing the old version. This was just a plan to mitigate some connection issues while we setup our new clusters with latest istio.